# Python + Cassandra 1.2 automatic table creation

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cql3

**Intro**

I'm writing an application in Python using a Cassandra 1.2 cluster (7 nodes, replication factor 3) and I'm accessing Cassandra from Python using the cql library (CQL 3.0).

**The problem**

The application is built in a way that when trying to run a cql statement against an unconfigured column family, it automatically creates the table and retries the cql statement. For example, if I try to run this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

And table1 doesn't exists, then the application will run the corresponding CREATE TABLE for table1 and will retry the previous select. The problem is that, after the creation of the table the SELECT (the retry) fails with this error:

```
Request did not complete within rpc_timeout
```

**The question**

I assume the cluster needs some time to propagate the creation of the table or something like that? If I wait a few seconds between the creation of the table and the retry of the select statement everything works, but I want to know exactly why and if there is a better way of doing it. Perhaps making the create table wait for the changes to propagate before returning?, is there a way of doing that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using cqlsh.  Default consistency level for cqlsh is one meaning it will return after the first node completes but not necessarily before all nodes complete.  If you read you aren't guaranteed to read from the node that has the completed table.  You can check this by turning on tracing but that will affect performance.

You can enforce [consistency](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/index) which should make that create wait until the table is created on all nodes.

```
CREATE TABLE ... USING CONSISTENCY ALL
```

Comment: No, I'm not using cqlsh, I'm accessing the table from python using the CQL 3.0 library. And yes, the consistency level "should" help me avoid this, but it is not. I already tested with consistency level ALL (months ago after posting this question) and the problem persists, the only solution so far is to wait a few seconds before starting using the table. It's not THAT big of a deal since this situation happens only once per table, but still I can't find a definitive answer of what's going on and a more elegant way of dealing with it.

Comment: I had assumed consistency extended to table creation, but it sounds like schema propagation is it's own separate headache.  There is some more information on this sort of problem here: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/vkCeBerFxUg

Comment: It is indeed. Seems like ppl are still having problems with it. In my case it has been working rock solid for over 2 years now with the wait. By reading the link you posted it seems like there is a wait time but the driver should make it transparent (not my case when I asked the question). Also I wasn't using 0.0.0.0 (nor I am now) as rpc address, so probably it just needs time and the old crappy driver I was using wasn't aware it needs to wait for schema changes to propagate.